# В редакторе открываются лишние вкладки

Tags: visual-studio-code, winscp

При использовании Visual Studio Code по умолчанию для открытия файлов через WinSCP ,при подключении через WinSCP и при открытии файлов , в Visual Studio Code открывается вкладка с файлом и еще 2 вкладки Code.exe и VS , путь у вкладок ведет к папки с WinSCP но самих файлов нет в папки.
Такое наблюдается только при использовании Visual Studio Code при открытии любых файлов , подобного не случается при использовании других редакторов.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла переустановка WinSCP

Answer (score 0):

В winscp проверьте путь к редактору. Winscp сам прописывает помимо путя к приложению еще рандомные. Удалите лишние и все заработает