# При открытии любого файла через sftp (WinSCP) в редакторе VSCode открываются еще два пустых файла VS и Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, winscp

[image: При этом файл VS всегда активный]

При этом файл VS изначально активный. В других редакторах такого не наблюдается.

Comment: Помогла переустановка программы WinSCP

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1000922/178576)?